# Gon not working with Devise because of current_user?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails 4 app was working brilliantly with Gon until I installed Devise today. Now I get the following error on all my pages...'wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)':

```
ArgumentError in Users#show
Showing ... app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #6):
1
2
3  <head>
4    <title></title>
5    <!-- Gon is used to set global JS variables from server side. -->
6    <%= include_gon%>
7    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I figured out that the problem was I was doing the following application_controller.rb:

```
Gon.global.user = current_user
```

And at that point current_user doesn't exist. Does anyone know why not and how to set a global user to use in js if I can't do it in application_controller?

Comment: Please show us what objects are you putting into `gon`. Looks like you're trying to put there a whole AR object to serialize it.

Comment: Trying to serialize a User entry.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. How about serializing its attributes only?

Comment: The User entry is a very small hash with email and firstname.